# GestureRecognizer doesn't work only in ios xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, mobile, layout, xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin.forms to do an app but,
for some reason, after I change this page, I turned the image bigger and added some grids, the gesturerecognizer  stopped work only in iphone, in android it works normally...cam someone see the problem in this code? because, so far, I can't.
I am creating a page programatically because of the template that I need.

```
private void CriaTela()
    {
        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;

        gridtextura.RowSpacing = 5;
        gridtextura.ColumnSpacing = 15;

        lstCategorias = lstCategorias.OrderBy(o => o.nome).ToList();

        foreach (var item in lstCategorias)
        {
            Grid GridContent = new Grid
            {
                RowSpacing = 0,
                //BackgroundColor = Color.Pink,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                RowDefinitions =
            {
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(8, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star) }
            }
            };

            var textura = new CachedImage();
            textura.Source = "texturaCateg";
            textura.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
            textura.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
            textura.Aspect = Aspect.Fill;

            GridContent.BindingContext = item;

            Grid boxColorView = new Grid
            {
                RowSpacing = 0,
              //  BackgroundColor = Color.Pink,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                RowDefinitions =
            {
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(8, GridUnitType.Star) }
            }
            };

            boxColorView.Children.Add(new BoxView { Color = Color.FromHex(item.corFundo), VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand }, 0, 1 );
            boxColorView.Children.Add(textura, 0, 1);

            boxColorView.Children.Add(new BoxView { VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand }, 0, 0);
            gridtextura.Children.Add(boxColorView, column, row);
            gridtextura.Children.Add(GridContent, column, row);

            //Qual categoria foi escolhida?
            var CliqueCategoria = new TapGestureRecognizer();

            CliqueCategoria.Tapped += (s, e) =>
            {
                CriaLoading();
                var stacklayout = s as Grid;
                categoriaEscolhida = (Categorias)stacklayout.BindingContext;
                ChamaProdutos();
            };

            GridContent.GestureRecognizers.Add(CliqueCategoria);
            GridContent.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;
            if (item.imagem != null && item.imagem != "")
            {
                int initIndex = item.imagem.IndexOf(',');
                string image = "";

                image = item.imagem.Substring(initIndex + 1);

                try
                {
                    GridContent.Children.Add(new CachedImage { Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(image))), VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand }, 0, 0);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    GridContent.Children.Add(new CachedImage { Source = "error.png", VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill, HeightRequest = 50, WidthRequest = 50 }, 0, 0);

                }
            }

            GridContent.Children.Add(new Label { Text = item.nome, TextColor = Color.FromHex(item.corTexto), FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Micro, typeof(Label)), FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand }, 0, 1 );

            if (column == 0)
            {
                column = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                column = 0;
                row++;
            }

        }

    }
```

---------------- edit-------------------

I know a bit more about this problemm...because now I have a image that is a button...and it was working...but now, it is over other image and then it doesnt work anymore...but it's over the other image...it's the same case of this code I posted here...I have a grid over other..at the same position and width and length...and the top grid doesnt receive the tap

Comment: There is a chance that some child element is capturing the taps and not letting them go through to parent grid. Try setting `InputTranparent = true` on `GridContent` child controls.

Comment: More details here : https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.InputTransparent/

Comment: all childreen should receive InputTranparent = true, right?

Comment: I know a bit more about this problemm...because now I am a image that is a button...and it was working...but now, it is over other image and then it doesnt work anymore...but it's over...it's the same case of this code I posted here...I have a grid over other..at the same position and width, length...and the top grid doesnt receive the tap

Comment: InputTranparent = true didn't work :/

Comment: "I know a bit more about this problemm...because now I have a image that is a button...and it was working...but now, it is over other image and then it doesnt work anymore...but it's over the other image...it's the same case of this code I posted here...I have a grid over other..at the same position and width and length...and the top grid doesnt receive the tap "

Comment: Maybe adding the tap gesture recognizer to topmost element might help.

Comment: boxviewcolor is the grid that is under the GridContent at the same position...grid content receives the gesture recognizer and it doesnt work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155204/discussion-between-g-sharada-and-joyce-de-lanna).

Comment: try absolute layout instead of grid. Or you can follow this https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/61925/how-to-make-the-dynamic-grid-view-and-make-it-clickable

Comment: I am trying with Relative but it's really dificult!!

Comment: try to put Tapped Gesture on your Image content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in xaml...The main grid was inside other grid...this other grid was creating the problem...I think maybe it was over the clicks